# Is there a way to reorder a collection of posts to read from top (oldest) to bottom (newest)?

Tags: formatting

After I complete a collection of posts, can I reorder them in reverse to read from the top (oldest post) to bottom (newest post)?

Answer (score 0):

You can reverse the order of the main query via the [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) action:

```
function wpa85668_ascending_order( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() )
        $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpa85668_ascending_order' );
```

If it's a custom query, just set the `order` query var to `ASC` in the arguments passed to the query.

Comment: Thanks for answering a newbie-researched question. I'll try your suggestion.